# apex:pageBlockTable conditionally rendered rows

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a list of records "ListAccountAttachments" and i want to show them on different tables according to field AccountAttachment.Folder__c

```
    *In my controller:

             public List<CustomAttachment__c> getListAccountAttachments()
                {    

                    return [select id,
                                   name,
                                   description__c,
                                   attachment__c,
                                   folder__c
                            from CustomAttachment__c
                            where account__c =:acct.id
                            ];      
                }

     *In my page i have two tables, first one (AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'):

               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccountAttachments}" var="AccountAttachment">
              <apex:column > 
                     <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>                                                    
                     <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.name}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column > 
                     <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.Description__c}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'}"/>                                                                          
                </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>    

    *Second table(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'):


                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccountAttachments}" var="AccountAttachment">
                            <apex:column > 
                                 <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>                                                    
                                 <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.name}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                             <apex:column > 
                                 <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                                 <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.Description__c}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'}"/>                                                                          
                            </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Result is:
[image]

The problem is empty rows  (indicated in yellow), for records not rendered.

Do you know how can i remove empty rows of record not showed?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

On top of the head i can think of 2 ways, i am not sure if these are the right way to do it and i havent tried it out myself so i might be wrong.

1. You could use the rendered attribute in apex:column, but might have to give it every column you have.
2. Have 2 different lists one for CS Attachment and other for TS attachment and use them in your pageblocktable separately instead of using one for both the pageblocktable

Update based on the comments (pls bear with me for any syntax errors)

```
// Once you have ListAccountAttachments populated


List<CustomAttachment__c> tsAttach = new List<CustomAttachment__c>();
   List<CustomAttachment__c> csAttach = new List<CustomAttachment__c>();
  for(CustomAttachment__c cA : ListAccountAttachments)
   {
     if(cA.Folder__c == 'TS attachment')
        tsAttach.Add(cA);
     else if(cA.Folder__c == 'CS attachment')
        csAttach.Add(cA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Prady. 1 )i will lose the headers of the table adding rendered conditions to columns. 2) I would like to use only one list. Do you have some other idea?

Comment: @Enry Visualforce doesn't provide any way to filter the rows except in the lists supplied in the apex:pageBlockTable so you'll have to use multiple lists (in some shape or form) as Prady suggests.

Comment: @Enry any particular reason you want to avoid using 2 lists? I cant see any other way unless you want to use standard html table with css and apex:repeat which really becomes complicated like assigning a class to table row which you want to hide using css to hide it. I would recommend using 2 lists instead of going through html css way

Comment: i was trying to avoid different queries.Now i have only one query and different lists filled with logic in the controller ;)

Comment: You dont have to do multiple queries, loop through ListAccountAttachments and then add check if folder__c == 'CS Attachemnt' add it csList else if folder__c== 'TS Attachemnt' add to tsList. Use the tslist and csList in the respective pageblocktables

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use rendered condition while displaying the data in different table.

```
*In my page i have two tables, first one (AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'):

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccountAttachments}" var="AccountAttachment">
          <apex:column rendered="{!IF(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment' ,TRUE,FALSE)}"> 
                 <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>                                                    
                 <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.name}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'}"/>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column rendered="{!IF(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment' ,TRUE,FALSE)}"> 
                 <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.Description__c}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='TS attachment'}"/>                                                                          
            </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>    

*Second table(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'):


             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccountAttachments}" var="AccountAttachment">
                        <apex:column rendered="{!IF(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment' ,TRUE,FALSE)}"> 
                             <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>                                                    
                             <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.name}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                         <apex:column rendered="{!IF(AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment' ,TRUE,FALSE)}"> 
                             <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                             <apex:outputText value="{!AccountAttachment.Description__c}" rendered="{!AccountAttachment.Folder__c=='CS attachment'}"/>                                                                          
                        </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```